# Can I use Nvidia Cuda cores and NVLINK for EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, gpu

This question mainly pertains to Nvidias development within Blender. I currently have a 2080 and I know that Cycles ustilizes CUDA cores for rendering. However I plan on purchasing 2 3090's whenever they pop into the market and NVLINK'ing them for development reasons. My question is can CUDA cores and NVLINK be utilized for EEVEE's rendering AND viewport?